# Magento - Extension Development, deal with uninstall

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am really new on magento extension development. I have learned from others and create a simple demo for magento 1.7.0 extension. It working well, in its install script, I added an attribute to "catalog_product", it's working too.

Now I am wondering, when this extension removed from system, or uninstalled from system, how can I remove this attribute, how to write code to deal with uninstall? Thanks.

Comment: Even though Magento defines `TYPE_DB_UNINSTALL` and `TYPE_DB_ROLLBACK` and kind of started to implement such functionality long ago, unfortunately they never fully implemented it (as of CE 1.8). You can see that in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::_getModifySqlFiles()`, for example. This means you're on your own with that.

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe we need to add uninstall link in the extension admin html..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...You cannot. Magento has some unfinished business. There is a method that probably was intended for this `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::_uninstallResourceDb($version)` but this is not called anyware.

```
protected function _uninstallResourceDb($version)
{
    $this->_modifyResourceDb(self::TYPE_DB_UNINSTALL, $version, '');
    return $this;
}
```

And even if you call it manually in your script it won't do anything because the method that is called inside it `_modifyResourceDb` does nothing when the first parameter is `self::TYPE_DB_UNINSTALL` ('uninstall'). It just handles the parameters `self::TYPE_DB_INSTALL` ('install') and `self::TYPE_DB_UPGRADE` ('upgrade').
And even if your try to uninstall the extension from the extensions manager, this only deletes the files.

```
public function processUninstallPackage($chanName, $package, $cacheObj, $configObj)
{
    $package = $cacheObj->getPackageObject($chanName, $package);
    $contents = $package->getContents();

    $targetPath = rtrim($configObj->magento_root, "\\/");
    foreach ($contents as $file) {
        $fileName = basename($file);
        $filePath = dirname($file);
        $dest = $targetPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        if(@file_exists($dest)) {
            @unlink($dest);
            $this->removeEmptyDirectory(dirname($dest));
        }
    }

    $destDir = $targetPath . DS . Mage_Connect_Package::PACKAGE_XML_DIR;
    $destFile = $package->getReleaseFilename() . '.xml';
    @unlink($destDir . DS . $destFile);
}
```

The moral thing to do in these cases it to include a small txt file in your extension (readme or something like that) explaining what needs to be removed from the database for uninstall. If you can provide the exact queries that would be even better.
**[Edit] - ugly workaround**
You can try to simulate the uninstall like this. Let's say that your extension has the version 1.3.0. Create an upgrade file that has the name `upgrade-1.3.0-2.0.0.php` that really contains an uninstall script. And for uninstalling just tell the the person using it to change the version in `config.xml` to `2.0.0`. Then your upgrade/uninstall script will run, and only after that remove the extension.

Comment: Off topic a bit. Take a look at other thing you should have in mind when creating an extension: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8344/146

Comment: Thanks. It's really unexpected. If we installed a lot similar extension, there will be many junk data in table after we removed them manually...

Comment: So it's impossible to do an uninstall script in Magento extension?

Comment: From what I know it's not possible. I've edited my answer and included an ugly workaround that might work. I haven't tested it yet. I just thought of it :)